# Onload event load jscript function var data but it not stop loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

SO I try to preview an image from bbcode decoder the code work fine but issue is I need that image inside `<a>` href link so that people can click it and get the image source and also I put massage on that like: CLICK ON IMAGE FOR FULL SIZE,

So I put here a simple Jscript function and inside it I call a `variable` and put `document.getElementById`,   after doing that then I put `variable.innerHTML` and put my image massage and `<a href>` value.

But when I run on my browser its just load like a **endless loop**. It just load over and over again.

Here is my full code: 1st code from php bbcode decoder and the 2nd code only html because I was not sure if my php code do that either way It not solving.

1st

```
    <script>
    function linkset(img) {
            var fio=document.getElementById(img.name);
            fio.innerHTML='<strong>Click on image for full size view.</strong><br /><a href="'+img.src+'" target="_blank">'+fio.innerHTML+'</a>';
    }
    </script> 




<?php

$img_count = 0;

function parseimage($matches)
{
    global $img_count;

    $img_count++;

    return "\n<div id=\"img{$img_count}\" style=\"font-size:x-small; display:inline;\">\n<img name=\"img{$img_count}\" onload='linkset(this);' src='$matches[1]' border='0' alt='' /></div>";
}

$content = "[img]https://www.technocrazed.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/beautiful-wallpaper-download-14.jpg[/img]";

$result = preg_replace_callback('/\[img\]((http|ftp|https):\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-\+\?\&\.\=\_\~\#\'\%\;]*))\[\/img\]/i', 'parseimage', $content);

?>

<?php echo $result; ?>
```

2nd

```
    <script>
    function linkset(img) {
            var fio=document.getElementById(img.name);
            fio.innerHTML='<strong>Click on image for full size view.</strong><br /><a href="'+img.src+'" target="_blank">'+fio.innerHTML+'</a>';
    }
    </script> 






<?php 

$ssq = "https://www.technocrazed.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/beautiful-wallpaper-download-14.jpg";

?>


<div id="img" style="font-size:x-small; display:inline;"><img name="img" onload="linkset(this);" src="<?php echo $ssq; ?>" border="0" alt="" /></div>
```

Result came like that:

```
<div id="img1" style="font-size:x-small; display:inline;">
<strong>Click on image for full size view.</strong><br>
<a href="https://www.technocrazed.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/beautiful-wallpaper-download-14.jpg" target="_blank">
<strong>Click on image for full size view.</strong><br></a>
<a href="https://www.technocrazed.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/beautiful-wallpaper-download-14.jpg" target="_blank">
<strong>Click on image for full size view.</strong><br></a>
<a href="https://www.technocrazed.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/beautiful-wallpaper-download-14.jpg" target="_blank">
<strong>Click on image for full size view.</strong><br></a>
<a href="https://www.technocrazed.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/beautiful-wallpaper-download-14.jpg" target="_blank">
<strong>Click on image for full size view.</strong><br></a>
<a href="https://www.technocrazed.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/beautiful-wallpaper-download-14.jpg" target="_blank">
<strong>Click on image for full size view.</strong><br></a>

<img name="img1" onload="linkset(this);" src="https://www.technocrazed.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/beautiful-wallpaper-download-14.jpg" alt="" border="0"></a>
</div>
```

This thing loop over and over but why??????????

```
<strong>Click on image for full size view.</strong><br>
<a href="https://www.technocrazed.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/beautiful-wallpaper-download-14.jpg" target="_blank">
<strong>Click on image for full size view.</strong><br></a>
```

Please Help........[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are you calling this code in a loop of some sort?

Comment: @El_Vanja
No no its just repeat over and over

Comment: You are calling the function on onload of the image. When you update the innerHTML the onload is called again thats why its running in a loop

Comment: @AbdullahRazzaki
So what can I do now?

Comment: Can You put some if statement like if(img=something) {var fio= whet ever.......}

Comment: @AsifUzZaman
Wait I am trying...

Comment: @AsifUzZaman
I try this.... it stop looping but goal is not achieved..... function linkset(img) {
        if (img.name==true) {
            var fio=document.getElementById(img.name);
            fio.innerHTML='<strong>Click on image for full size view.</strong><br /><a href="'+img.src+'" target="_blank">'+fio.innerHTML+'</a>';
        }
    }

Comment: May I ask why you aren't adding this content in PHP? You have all the necessary data.

Comment: @El_Vanja
Maybe you are right but this one of my bbcode decoder function code so I needed in Java

Comment: You could check if an `<a>` tag already exists inside the div in your `linkset` function and do nothing if it does.

Comment: Ok... Check answar

Comment: If the code work please vate me

Comment: @AsifUzZaman
Yes its working and thank you for php code.... remove my js code......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,,,,,,,, There is 2 way I tested....
1st is in JS obviously

```
<script>
function linkset(img) {
        var massnlink='<strong>Click on image for full size view.</strong><br /><a href="'+img.src+'" target="_blank">'+img.name;
        var photo='<img name="img" src="'+img.src+'" border="0" alt="" /></a>';
        img1.innerHTML = massnlink + photo;
}
</script>
```

you can replace you js code

here if all code:

```
    <script>
    function linkset(img) {
            var massnlink='<strong>Click on image for full size view.</strong><br /><a href="'+img.src+'" target="_blank">'+img.name;
            var photo='<img name="img" src="'+img.src+'" border="0" alt="" /></a>';
            img1.innerHTML = massnlink + photo;
    }
    </script> 
<?php

$img_count = 0;

function parseimage($matches)
{
    global $img_count;

    $img_count++;

    return "\n<div id=\"img{$img_count}\" style=\"font-size:x-small; display:inline;\">\n<img name=\"img{$img_count}\" onload='linkset(this);' src='$matches[1]' border='0' alt='' /></div>";
}

$content = "[img]https://www.technocrazed.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/beautiful-wallpaper-download-14.jpg[/img]";

$result = preg_replace_callback('/\[img\]((http|ftp|https):\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-\+\?\&\.\=\_\~\#\'\%\;]*))\[\/img\]/i', 'parseimage', $content);

?>

<?php echo $result; ?>
```

And 2nd thing is that?????? why you need JS code??? you can use PHP all in all
Here is the code:

```
<?php

$img_count = 0;

function parseimage($matches)
{
    global $img_count;

    $img_count++;

    return "\n<div id=\"img{$img_count}\" style=\"font-size:x-small; display:inline;\">\n<br>\n<a href='$matches[1]'><strong>Click on image for full size view.</strong><img name=\"img{$img_count}\" onload='linkset(this);' src='$matches[1]' border='0' alt='' /></a></div>";
}

$content = "[img]https://www.technocrazed.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/beautiful-wallpaper-download-14.jpg[/img]";

$result = preg_replace_callback('/\[img\]((http|ftp|https):\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-\+\?\&\.\=\_\~\#\'\%\;]*))\[\/img\]/i', 'parseimage', $content);

?>

<?php echo $result; ?>
```

I can not discuss about PHP code cause it is so easy to understand.... But if you want I can give you note in comment.